# Still getting white color background color in table view within a container view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I have a table view that is embedded within a container view, now I have the color set correctly for the cells (background) however, it still shows white below the last cell.  Is there any way to change that so that is the same as the background color around the cells? Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Below the help cell and before the bottom VIEW it is white... that is what I'm having a problem changing.

Comment: You can use the "view hierarchy" to debug it

Answer (score 1):

I would like to give some approach below

1. Make sure your table view already set background color to clear color.
2. Set your view controller background color to your color.

Comment: I tried both suggestions and I am still not able to fix this.

Comment: One thing I should mention I have a container view that contains the table view controller and table view.  I have set the container view to clear along with the top view controller but that didn't work either.